# How to set maximum connection axis camera?

Tags: ip-camera

I use the AXIS P5532-E camera. I need more connections to cam. However, I get the error "503 service unavailable, the maximum number of clients are already connected".
Is it possible to increase the maximum number of connections to the camera?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is not. According to the [Axis FAQ](https://www.axis.com/support/faq//FAQ115841) it may be limited due to hardware limitations.